# How to provide contribute without edit permissions?

Tags: permissions, list-form, out-of-the-box

I have a list where user will have a form to submit (so i have to provide contribute access), but they should only view their own items(separate view i have) and cannot edit. Which permissions do i need to give?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a **custom permission level** by copying the `contribute permission level` and remove `Edit items` option.

**To create a permission level**

- Open the site collection site (the root site not a subsite)
- Go to site setting.
- below Users and Permission > Click on Site Permission.
- From the above ribbon, > click on permission level to be able to create a new permission level.

[image]

For more details check

- [How to create a new SharePoint permissions level](https://billing.plexhosted.com/knowledgebase/278/How-to-create-a-new-SharePoint-2013-permissions-level-.html)
- [Configure custom permissions in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263239.aspx)
- [Understanding permission levels in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understanding-permission-levels-in-SharePoint-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Alternative solution using Item level permission

[image]

For more details check [How to enable Item Level Permissions in SharePoint](http://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-enable-item-level-permissions-in-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 8):

You can create your own permission level same as **contribute**, but without edit option.

Below is the link for reference.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263239.aspx

Comment: the same thinking , in the same time . sorry for duplicating :)

Comment: Thanks but its same link as above comment. ;)

Answer (score 8):

You can use that Standard available Contribute Permission profile

Your "View Own Items" restriction is a setting on the List, not in the Permission profile

[image]

Comment: Thanks but the above comments worked too :)