# SharePoint Tabs permissions

Tags: custom-permission-level

I have created a ticket tracker with three tabs. New, Assigned, and Completed.
I would like to know if there is a way in SP 2013 to give each tab separate permissions. I would like to give Read, Edit, and Contribute to the first tab New. I would like to give Read only view to the Assigned, and Completed tabs to the submitters or hide the edit tabs in each new submission. I'm new at the game so any advice would be appreciated.

Thank You, DC

Comment: How did you create the tabs? Custom JavaScript, a web part, ...
Are you asking about groups in a View?

Answer (score 0):

You want to handle your permissions in the lists themselves, not in the tab view. You want to allow people the Create permission but not the Edit or Delete permission.  If you do this the UI will reflect the appropriate view to the user automatically.

To do this you'll probably need to create a custom permission level. Here's an answer that shows how to do this:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/217570/8056

Another thing about security: If you try to enforce security through a custom UI rather than on the underlying data, users will just bypass your page and go straight to the lists themselves to do what they need to do, circumventing all your effort.